# Default load in combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008

If I want to load for example a default country when the combobox shows up ("Country: Lebanon"), how do I do so?
I am using VS2008 (C#). Thank you.

Comment: Winforms? WebForms? WPF? What have you tried? Can you post your code?

Answer (score 1):

Add some items to the Combobox...it is just a sample, you can run a loop also to add items.

```
combobox1.Items.Add("USA");
combobox1.Items.Add("England");
combobox1.Items.Add("Kenya");
combobox1.Items.Add("South Africa");
```

Now your Combobox has four items. To select a specific country try this:

```
combobox1.Text = "USA";
```

To select a on the index basis, try this:

```
combobox1.SelectedIndex = 0; // For USA
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use another method to add items in comboBox:

```
comboBox1.Items.Insert(0, "Egypt"); 
//the first item is the item index and the second is the item object.
```

Answer (score 0):

You would usually just set `myCombo.SelectedValue = "Whatever value"` as soon as the form is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of `SelectedValue`, `SelectedIndex`, `SelectedItem` or `SelectedText` properties of the [`ComboBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.aspx) control.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
myCombo.SelectedIndex = lebanonsIndex;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set selected index in Form load event

If Lebanon is first in `comboboxItem selectedIndex = 0`;
Example:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set it by using IndexOf in the Items collection

```
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = comboBox1.Items.IndexOf("Lebanon");// case sensitive
```

Answer (score 0):

This could work. Copy this code in your app.config file within appsettings.

```
< add key="DefaultCountry" value="Lebanon" />
```

and copy this at ur win form where you want to view it.

```
combobox1.Text = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultCountry"].ToString();.<add key="DefaultCountry" value="Lebanon"/>
```